How can I make one background image take up full screen?
I am creating a Offcanvas navbar from Bootrap. when I add a background image as url from google, the image returns as slip into 6 same images instead of one whole piece. What have I done wrong?
I went on w3schools and found some information nevertheless I still need some help on this? I know its something simple, please assist me?

There is no way we can help reliably without seeing the relevant code Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example However, having said that it sounds as if you need to set no-repeat on the background image and make the background size cover. See MDN for details. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

I think you should try to get this effect by creating a custom CSS class. You can apply a class like this to the div that you want to have the background.
.background-image {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url( // url or file location );
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

The key attribute you're probably missing is background-size: cover;
